# Android app on Chromebook failing to use view / get user events

Tags: java, android, delphi, view, chromebook

I use Delphi to create multi platform app.
It works on Android. On Chromebook it started failing after Chrome OS update some time ago.
Delphi uses own Windows handling.

Initially mNativeContentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); in NativeActivity gave some null pointer exception.

After some adaption I get the user interface as made in Delphi but it does not respond to any clicks/touch from user.
I have some clock with a timer so I can see the application is alive only it cannot be "clicked".

On https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/input-compatibility I found mentioned difference for Android and Chromebook:

In free-form window mode, the apps caption bar is part of your view hierarchy and under your control.
You generally do not have to be aware of this, but there are cases where you have to be careful:

Do not fiddle with Window.getDecorView().
If you want to add top-level views, add them to the view you have set as Activity.setContentView().

Delphi is using window.getDecorView.

If I look in Android sources I see for NativeActivity :
setContentView(mNativeContentView);

mNativeContentView is a private member.

So this gives me some questions:

1) Does this mean there is no way at al to try to replace the window.getDecorView by mNativeContentView?
   Can I access mNativeContentView somehow?

2) Is there another way to get it working as top window getting the mouse/touch events on Chromebook?

3) In logs I can see :
   SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing SurfaceView ...
   duplicate layer name: changing Background for -SurfaceView - ...

```
 This does not occur on real Android tablet obly on Chromebook.
```

Is this just a harmless warning or does it indicate the error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by overriding dispatchTouchEvent in the derived NativeActivity class.
Added explicit dispatchTouchEvent for top view in case normal Activity.dispatchTouchEvent does not handle it.